# How to get div to align at bottom of container div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vs9a4toz/

I want my buttons to be at the bottom of their divs.

I tried using `align-self: flex-end` on their container div. But that ends up with the content of that div gets aligned at the end not the div itself.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  size: 100px;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box1">
    <div class="content">
      <p>HEJ</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>ONEONE</button>
      <button>TWOTWO</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <div class="content">
      <p>HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ </p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>ONEONE</button>
      <button>TWOTWO</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box3">
    <div class="content">
      <p>HEJ</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>ONEONE</button>
      <button>TWOTWO</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: All you need is to add `flex-grow: 1` to `content` ... https://jsfiddle.net/vs9a4toz/2/ ... which you have to if you want to give the `content` a background color ... https://jsfiddle.net/vs9a4toz/3/ ... as with `margin-top: auto` that will not look good ... https://jsfiddle.net/vs9a4toz/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/eLuyursq/

```
.buttons {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Just add `margin-top: auto;`

Comment: +1 for the cleanest solution and [Flexbox and "margin-(opposite direction):auto" - relevant article](https://hackernoon.com/flexbox-s-best-kept-secret-bd3d892826b6)

Comment: @FelipeAls Give the `content` a background color and suddenly this is not that good anymore...check my comment at the question

Answer (score 3):

`flex-grow: 1` on `.content` is enough to make this work:

```
.content {
  text-align:center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

It will take all available free space within the `.box` column.
(Thanks @LGSon)

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin` property with flexbox

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  size: 100px;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box1">
    <div class="content">
      <p>HEJ</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>ONEONE</button>
      <button>TWOTWO</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <div class="content">
      <p>HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ </p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>ONEONE</button>
      <button>TWOTWO</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box3">
    <div class="content">
      <p>HEJ</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>ONEONE</button>
      <button>TWOTWO</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute positioning, please see code below:

```
.buttons{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    size: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bsd

check it out

https://jsfiddle.net/u1bx4473/1/

you need to `position:relative` the divs and then `position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%` the buttons...

but if you need the content to not get hidden by the buttons, you need a container for the content with `overflow:auto` and fixed width or something...

kind of like this : https://jsfiddle.net/u1bx4473/2/

Answer (score 0):

A solution using padding on content and absolute position on the buttons:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  size: 100px;
  position:relative;
}

.content {
  text-align:center;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.buttons {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box1">
    <div class="content">
      <p>HEJ</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button>ONEONE</button>
        <button>TWOTWO</button>
    </div>
  </div> 
  
    <div class="box2">
    <div class="content">
      <p>HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ </p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button>ONEONE</button>
        <button>TWOTWO</button>
    </div>
  </div> 
  
    <div class="box3">
    <div class="content">
      <p>HEJ</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button>ONEONE</button>
        <button>TWOTWO</button>
    </div>
  </div> 

</div>
```